# Aws lambda function to filter describe_images function with only name and tag values

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, image, aws-lambda, boto3

Have AMI's on AWS with different tags like this

AMI 1 :

```
key         value
modified_by mark
```

AMI 2 :

```
key         value
modified_by Tom
```

AMI

Tried this filter to fetch only name and modified_by values .

```
    
    ec2_client = boto3.client('ec2', region_name='ap-east-1') 
    images = ec2_client.describe_images(Owners=['self'],Filters=[{'Name': 'modified_by', 'Values': ['Tom']}])
```

Got this error

```
 "errorMessage": "An error occurred (InvalidParameterValue) when calling the DescribeImages operation: The filter 'modified_by' is invalid"
```

How to call filter describe_images() function using boto3 in aws lambda to get only name of instance and modified_by only

Answer (score 2):

Your filters are not correct.

From the boto3 [docs](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.Client.describe_images).

> **tag :key** - The key/value combination of a tag assigned to the
> resource. Use the tag key in the filter name and the tag value as the
> filter value. For example, to find all resources that have a tag with
> the key Owner and the value TeamA , specify tag:Owner for the filter
> name and TeamA for the filter value.

> **tag-key** - The key of a tag assigned to the resource. Use this filter to find all resources assigned a tag with a specific key, regardless of the tag value.

So for example:

```
images = ec2_client.describe_images(Owners=['self'],Filters=[{'Name': 'tag-key', 'Values': ['Tom']}])
```

Will list all instances that have a tag with a value "Tom", regardless of their tag key.

and

```
images = ec2_client.describe_images(Owners=['self'],Filters=[{'Name': 'tag:modified-by', 'Values': ['Tom']}])
```

will list all images which have tag "modified-by" with value "Tom"